# PHP MVC pass data in response object to body(view)?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, response

I am using php + blade and wrote simple mvc and now I am wondering how to pass data to view.
My response object contains header, status code and body(view). Is it ok to pass data to response body section next to view?
`->setBody(['view'=>'result','somedata'=>$somedata]);`

or response object should have statuscode, header, body(view), and data separately from body(view)?

now in controller i have:

```
return Response::create()
    ->setStatusCode(200)
    ->setHeader(['Content-Type' => 'text/html'])
    ->setBody(['view'=>'result']);
```

my response class:

```
class response implements ResponseInterface
{
    protected $statusCode;
    protected $headers;
    protected $body=[];

    public function setStatusCode(string $code) :object
    {
        $this->statusCode = $code;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setHeader(array $header):object
    {
        $this->headers=$header;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setBody(array $body): object
    {
        $this->body = $body;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatusCode():string
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }
    public function getHeaders():array
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }
    public function getBody():array
    {
        return $this->body;
    }
    public static function create(string $statusCode = null, array $headers = null, string $body = null): response
    {
        return new Response($statusCode, $headers, $body);
    }
    public function send(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->headers as $header => $value) {
            header(strtoupper($header).': '.$value);
        }

        if ($this->headers['Content-Type']==="text/html" && $this->statusCode === "200") {
            View::renderTemplate($this->body['view']);
        }


    }
}
```

i am able to pass data like this, by adding fx datatable variable in controllers and it works:

```
 return Response::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setHeader(['Content-Type' => 'text/html'])
        ->setBody(['view'=>'result','datatable'=>$datatable]);
```

and then need to adjust response send action to:

```
public function send(): void
{
    foreach ($this->headers as $header => $value) {
        header(strtoupper($header).': '.$value);
    }

    if ($this->headers['Content-Type']==="text/html" && $this->statusCode === "200") {
        View::renderTemplate($this->body['view'],'datatable'=>$this->body['datatable']);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Response factory

A Response instance shouldn't be responsible for creating a Response object. This task should be performed by a *Response factory*. An example:

```
class ResponseFactory extends MessageFactory implements ResponseFactoryInterface {

    //...

    public function createResponse(int $code = 200, string $reasonPhrase = ''): ResponseInterface {
        return new Response($this->body, $code, $reasonPhrase, $this->headers, $this->protocolVersion);
    }

    //...

}
```

#### Response emitter

A Response instance shouldn't be responsible for sending the response headers of a HTTP response. This task, along with printing the content of the Response body to screen, should be performed by a *Response emitter*. An example:

```
class ResponseEmitter implements ResponseEmitterInterface {

    //...

    public function emit(ResponseInterface $response): void {
        $this
            ->checkHeadersSent()
            ->sendStatusLine($response)
            ->sendResponseHeaders($response)
            ->outputBody($response)
        ;

        exit();
    }

    //...

}
```

#### Template renderer/engine

A Response instance shouldn't be responsible for rendering template files (also known as *views*). So, it shouldn't be coupled to any template renderer or `View` instance in order to render template files. The task of rendering template files should be performed by a *template renderer/engine*. An example:

```
class TemplateRenderer extends BaseTemplateRenderer implements TemplateRendererInterface {

    //...

    public function render(string $templateName, array $context = []): string {
        $templateFile = $this->templatesPath . $this->buildTemplateName($templateName);

        $this
            ->validateTemplateFile($templateFile)
            ->saveContextValuesToContextCollection($context)
        ;

        return $this->renderTemplateFile($templateFile);
    }

    private function renderTemplateFile(string $filename): string {
        ob_start();

        extract($this->contextCollection->all());

        require $filename;

        $content = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        return $content;
    }

    //...

}
```

The rendered content (a *string*!) is then passed to the body of a Response instance.

#### Example

Here is the example of a class, whose method `addUser` is responsible for rendering the given template file, creating a Response instance, writing the rendered content to the Response body and returning the Response.

```
/**
 * A view to handle the users.
 */
class Users extends Primary {

    //...

    /**
     * Add a user.
     * 
     * @return ResponseInterface The response to the current request.
     */
    public function addUser(): ResponseInterface {
        $bodyContent = $this->templateRenderer->render('@Templates/Users/Users.html.twig', [
            'activeNavItem' => 'Users',
            'message' => 'User successfully added',
            'users' => $this->getAllUsers(),
        ]);

        $response = $this->responseFactory->createResponse();
        $response->getBody()->write($bodyContent);

        return $response;
    }

    //...

}
```

The Response returned by `Users:addUser` is further processed by a Response emitter. Its body content is finally printed on screen.

```
// Create a request.
$request = $container->get('request');

// Create a middleware queue.
$middlewareQueue = $container->get('middleware-queue');

// Handle the request and produce a response.
$response = $middlewareQueue->handle($request);

// Emit the response.
$responseEmitter = $container->get('response-emitter');
$responseEmitter->emit($response);
```

#### Back to... your simplified Response

So, in your case, Response could be simplified to the following. It is up to you to develop the rest of the components - the ones that I mentioned above.

```
class Response implements ResponseInterface {

    public function getStatusCode(): int {
        //...
    }

    public function setStatusCode(int $code): static {
        //...
    }

    public function getHeaders(): array {
        //...
    }

    public function setHeader(array $header): static {
        //...
    }

    public function getBody(): string {
        //...
    }

    public function setBody(string $content): static {
        //...
    }

}
```

*Note*: If you are using `return $this;` in a method, then use `static` instead of `object` as the returned data type.

#### Some suggestions

If I may, I would suggest you to develop an MVC-based application which uses external libraries for its components. For example, instead of developing your own implementation of HTTP message (Request, Response, URI, uploaded files, etc) - which would take you a very long time!, I'd recommend to use [Laminas Diactoros](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-diactoros/) package. Or to use [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) as the template engine and renderer for your application. And so on.

*Note*: By the way, [the *render* method](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#rendering-templates) of the Twig template engine will give you the answer to your question (*Is it ok to pass data to response body section next to view?*).

Also, for your PHP applications, if you didn't do it already, I'd suggest to follow the [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/).

#### Resources

- [Sandro Mancuso : Crafted Design](https://vimeo.com/107963074)
- [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) (especially 1, 4, 7, 11, 12, 15, 17)
- [PHP-DI - The dependency injection container for humans](https://php-di.org/)
- [FastRoute - Fast request router for PHP](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute)
- [Twig - The flexible, fast, and secure template engine for PHP](https://twig.symfony.com/)
- [Laminas Diactoros](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-diactoros/) - an implementation of the PSR-7 HTTP message interfaces, as well as the PSR-17 HTTP message factory interfaces
- [PHP-DI Invoker](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Invoker), to invoke any PHP callable, like controller methods

Comment: Thanks i will take a look about facory and emitters. its simple project which I wrote to learn php, so i am beginer. I learned laravel for while and come back to pure php to find out whats exactly going on in backstage of application - to understand responses, requests and stuff :) thanks for your time.